# Can't exit full view

Tags: front-end, keyboard

When coding I accidently pressed some shortcut that lead to a full screen without the option to clode or minimize the window. I have windows.

Even if I close the file and open it again, it opens with the same setting. Does anyone know how to exit this mode? [image]

The printscreen is of my entire screen the top bar is hidden.

Comment: F12 toggles between full screen mode and normal mode on my system. Does that help?

Comment: ... or (for Windows) right mouse click, and bottom option is "Toggle Full Screen"

Answer (score 7):

Google ["Mathematica full screen shortcut"](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Mathematica%20full%20screen%20shortcut)

[image]

Go to the [first link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/FullScreen.html)

[image]

> On Windows and Unix/Linux, use <kbd>F12</kbd> to toggle Full Screen.
>
> On Mac OS X, the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>.